# Connection the VerneMQ MQTT failing which is installed on local Windows 10 Docker engine

Tags: docker, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

I got the Docker version - Docker Desktop 4.3.0 (71786) installed on my machine. I am trying to install the VerneMQ on Docker using the following command -

```
docker run -d -p 1883:1883 -e "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=on" -e "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA=yes" --name vernemq1 -d erlio/docker-vernemq
```

Docker logs for the contianer are as follows -

```
config is OK

-config /vernemq/data/generated.configs/app.2021.12.14.09.57.29.config -args_file /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args -vm_args /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args

Exec:  /vernemq/bin/../erts-10.2.3/bin/erlexec -boot /vernemq/bin/../releases/1.10.0/vernemq               -config /vernemq/data/generated.configs/app.2021.12.14.09.57.29.config -args_file /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args -vm_args /vernemq/bin/../etc/vm.args              -pa /vernemq/bin/../lib/erlio-patches -- console -noshell -noinput

Root: /vernemq/bin/..

09:57:30.806 [info] writing state {[{[{actor,<<21,128,87,20,226,202,145,175,203,97,17,207,239,134,39,35,203,238,93,163>>}],1}],{dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[['VerneMQ@172.17.0.2',{[{actor,<<21,128,87,20,226,202,145,175,203,97,17,207,239,134,39,35,203,238,93,163>>}],1}]],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}} to disk <<75,2,131,80,0,0,0,248,120,1,203,96,206,97,96,96,96,204,96,130,82,41,12,172,137,201,37,249,69,185,64,81,17,209,134,112,145,71,167,38,174,63,157,40,120,254,125,155,186,242,233,119,177,139,179,18,25,179,50,56,83,24,88,82,50,147,75,18,25,19,5,128,144,35,49,32,209,32,67,32,11,13,100,48,130,196,192,6,131,8,166,20,6,161,176,212,162,188,84,223,64,7,67,115,35,61,67,115,61,3,61,35,210,108,70,181,1,225,14,6,194,238,64,213,10,0,36,44,78,211>>

09:57:30.827 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/0 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,43756361}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:31.273 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/1 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,54479016}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:31.585 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/2 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,45466763}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:31.914 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/3 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,33567655}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:32.245 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/4 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,47595779}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:32.699 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/5 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,39556020}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:33.062 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/6 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,61685232}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:33.379 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/7 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,55978245}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:33.688 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/8 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,34857794}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:34.016 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/9 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,59026771}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:34.474 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/10 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,51575312}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:34.888 [info] Datadir ./data/meta/meta/11 options for LevelDB: [{open,[{block_cache_threshold,33554432},{block_restart_interval,16},{block_size_steps,16},{compression,true},{create_if_missing,true},{delete_threshold,1000},{eleveldb_threads,71},{fadvise_willneed,false},{limited_developer_mem,false},{sst_block_size,4096},{tiered_slow_level,0},{total_leveldb_mem_percent,6},{use_bloomfilter,true},{write_buffer_size,49221877}]},{read,[{verify_checksums,true}]},{write,[{sync,false}]},{fold,[{verify_checksums,true},{fill_cache,false}]}]

09:57:35.579 [info] Try to start vmq_plumtree: ok

09:57:40.035 [info] Try to start vmq_generic_msg_store: ok

09:57:40.151 [info] loaded 0 subscriptions into vmq_reg_trie

09:57:40.153 [info] cluster event handler 'vmq_cluster' registered

09:57:44.398 [warning] session stopped abnormally due to '{cant_parse_connect_fixed_header,<<"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:1883\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nOrigin: chrome-extension://hemojaaeigabkbcookmlgmdigohjobjm\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: M4Jd7MuPOr8ENM1q4wsqpQ==\r\nSec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: mqttv3.1\r\n\r\n">>}'
```

Docker inspect result -

```
[
    {
        "Id": "28c7f34dfe5af201b7786a8b14d4a856914fac0d88d528a3f335c910",
        "Created": "2021-12-14T09:57:24.5409484Z",
        "Path": "start_vernemq",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 19341,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-12-14T10:04:56.1632278Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-12-14T10:03:05.3115524Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "healthy",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2021-12-14T10:01:31.8393179Z",
                        "End": "2021-12-14T10:01:32.4156947Z",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2021-12-14T10:02:02.5563049Z",
                        "End": "2021-12-14T10:02:03.0990371Z",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2021-12-14T10:02:33.2237707Z",
                        "End": "2021-12-14T10:02:33.7814843Z",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2021-12-14T10:03:03.9905476Z",
                        "End": "2021-12-14T10:03:04.5533888Z",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2021-12-14T10:05:26.1645268Z",
                        "End": "2021-12-14T10:05:26.7281332Z",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c313a97d55f84087e216fb18c06e0f410f5ded6ee089c5",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/28c7f34dfe5af201b6914fac0d88d528a3f335c910/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/28c7f34dfe5af8b14d4a856914fac0d88d528a3f335c910/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/28c7f34dfe5af20d88d528a3f335c910/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/28c7f34dfe5af201ac0d88d528a3f335c910/28c7f34dfe5af201b77a941b00c86a8b14d4a856914fac0d88
d528a3f335c910-json.log",
        "Name": "/vernemq1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "1883/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "1883"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                24,
                162
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6738d5b2c9b935c3e90e370c21d03a5-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b48a41a3
92eb834cafd6f1579f005/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2237dca228f720bd3a37e53ba6b74fdfb/diff:/var/
lib/docker/overlay2/8f7ee085d6a04e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/18116350a96478ab3bb8250c294e58643d02a48bd89808e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/94f83d29c8304416d9709b034f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1780d5340ed788d9c9f/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6730c21d03a5/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67383a5/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6738d5b2370c21d03a5/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "77d02c57bafdc9275cc6bc",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/77d02c57bafdc92750b6cc6bc/_data",
                "Destination": "/vernemq/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "bb3402031f3fd09c821d41db",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/bb3402031f3f9c821d41db/_data",
                "Destination": "/vernemq/etc",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "3f79aa44ce3328f73c1093",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/3f79aa44cead0ec3c1093/_data",
                "Destination": "/vernemq/log",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "28c4dfe5a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "vernemq",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "1883/tcp": {},
                "4369/tcp": {},
                "44053/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {},
                "8883/tcp": {},
                "8888/tcp": {},
                "9100/tcp": {},
                "9101/tcp": {},
                "9102/tcp": {},
                "9103/tcp": {},
                "9104/tcp": {},
                "9105/tcp": {},
                "9106/tcp": {},
                "9107/tcp": {},
                "9108/tcp": {},
                "9109/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=on",
                "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ACCEPT_EULA=yes",
                "PATH=/vernemq/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR=app=vernemq",
                "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LOG__CONSOLE=console",
                "VERNEMQ_VERSION=1.10.0"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "start_vernemq"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "vernemq ping | grep -q pong"
                ]
            },
            "Image": "erlio/docker-vernemq",
            "Volumes": {
                "/vernemq/data": {},
                "/vernemq/etc": {},
                "/vernemq/log": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/vernemq",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b3906e648f42f4ed49f98e521",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "1883/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "1883"
                    }
                ],
                "4369/tcp": null,
                "44053/tcp": null,
                "8080/tcp": null,
                "8883/tcp": null,
                "8888/tcp": null,
                "9100/tcp": null,
                "9101/tcp": null,
                "9102/tcp": null,
                "9103/tcp": null,
                "9104/tcp": null,
                "9105/tcp": null,
                "9106/tcp": null,
                "9107/tcp": null,
                "9108/tcp": null,
                "9109/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/b3906e6f42",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "6e5e5d38da00cc6c6cc",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:48:ac:11:11:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "1a2a19e811b79bbb7e6dca53047fc1a",
                    "EndpointID": "6e5e5d38da00ca77724b7586c6cc",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And now when I try to connect to VerneMQ, I can't. I am trying to connect using TCP://172.17.0.2 over 1883 port.

Can somebody help me where I am making the mistake.

Note: I haven't changed the config file.

***EDIT:***
Using MQTTLens chrome extension to connect with MQTT.
[image]

***EDIT2***
I was trying to connect using various MQTT clients available but none of them seems to be working for me. but when accessing the broker using C# code (MQTTnet Nuget package) it seemed to be working. The only issue which I am facing right now is the MQTT Version.

When I set the Version as MqttProtocolVersion.V500 connection throws exception and the error which I will get is
`10:48:57.303 [warning] invalid protocol version for {[],undefined} 5`.

Now the question that remains is, how to configure the VerneMQ container to accept the latest Protocol V500?

```
var factory = new MqttFactory();
mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();           
var temp_options = new MqttClientOptions() { ClientId = clientId };
temp_options.ChannelOptions = new MqttClientTcpOptions()
{
    Server = ipAddress,
    Port = port
};   
temp_options.CleanSession = true;
temp_options.KeepAlivePeriod = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
temp_options.ProtocolVersion = MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V311;
//temp_options.ProtocolVersion = MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V500;         
await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(temp_options, CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: The last entry in the log implies you are trying to connect with a MQTT over WebSockets client not a native MQTT client. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70347128/edit) the question to give more information about how you are testing this.

Comment: @hardillb using MQTTLens chrome extension to connect with MQTT. FYI, Connection to Mosquitto broker on my local is successful using the same extention.

Comment: Try a different test client

Comment: @hardillb Tried MQTTX, ExplorerMQTT, but no luck. Used MQTT, TCP and WS protocols

Comment: Then show the logs from those connections. At the moment all we have to go on is an attempted connection from a WebSocket client.

Comment: I tried but no logs were produced for these connections. @hardillb

Comment: Are you attempting to connect from the host running Docker? If so try `localhost` (`tcp://127.0.0.1:1883`) - as you have bound the port this should work.

Comment: I can connect to broker using my C# code but any MQTT Client ie MQTTLens etc. Also now my broker is only working on Protocol 311, while I want my broker to run on 500. @Brits

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.vernemq.com/configuring-vernemq/listeners#allowed-protocol-versions). V5 is not enabled by default